# How to allow preformatted text being served by g-wan?

Tags: html, minify, g-wan

By default G-WAN strips white spaces from `HTML` files to minimize the file.
What's the best way to allow pre-formatted text defined by `<pre>` tag to get through?

@Richard Heath
Interesting -- I'm using a vanilla installation of G-Wan with the `<pre>` block starting like this `<pre class="fragment">`. 
See sample of doxygen generated doc

This is being hosted up on a vanilla installation of g-wan.

Update:
As a temporary (not clean/quick fix) work around, I've changed the startup to look like this:
`START=""`
...
`nohup ./$NAME $START &>/dev/null &`

I will try later to write a handler to filter the return.

**updated** sample files for comparison
`./gwan -d`
http://alex4u2nv.com/test/test.html
`nohup ./gwan &> /dev/null &`
http://alex4u2nv.com/docs/test.html

Comment: Can you add a sample html. G-WAN will not minimize when running in terminal(no -d). On my case G-WAN is not stripping white space in HTML (wrapped in pre tag) even in daemon mode.

Comment: You're right -- Seems like the issue only affects daemon mode.

Comment: This is because HTML, CSS and JS **minifying** is documented as only acting in **daemon mode** to let developers debug and trace Javascript. But the minifying glitch above is real and will be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [this link showing both preformated source code and text](http://gwan.com/en_bench.html) then it is clear that G-WAN v3.3 respects the `<pre>` tag even when running in daemon mode.

If you have an example of a broken page then publish the broken text rather than such a huge HTML page.

Further, in the link you provide the text is NOT broken but there is a client script that blocks the Internet Browser (one has to stop Javascript to see the whole page).

Comment: I've switched switched out of daemon mode to get it to work. I will set up a testbed that runs gwan -d with a smaller page for testing later.

Comment: Gil, here's the slimmed down pages for comparison: 
http://alex4u2nv.com/test/test.html 
http://alex4u2nv.com/docs/test.html

Comment: Thanks. It will be given a look.

Comment: Thanks. Tracing the code of the development version the minifying works as expected with your file so this was fixed in the past months. Thanks anyway for the feedback: more recently a glitch was found with embedded JS comments in HTML!